# Fail to access Flask-Login current_user after redirection from OpenID connect provider callback

Tags: flask, flask-login

I am using an openID provider to authenticate my flask app's users. After authentication on the authentication website, the provider sends my callback endpoint an id_token carrying the user's information as a `POST` request.

I decode this token, create the user object and save it in cache. After saving the user, the user is logged in using `flask_login.login_user()` the function redirects to the homepage

```
@app.route("/opentoken", methods=['POST'])
def openid_callback():
    token = request.form['id_token']
    decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, verify=False)
    preferred_username = decoded_token['preferred_username']
    user = save_user(preferred_username, decoded_token)
    login_user(user)
    log.info(current_user) #That confirms the current_user has the user info
    return redirect('/home')
```

The expected behavior is that on redirection the home endpoint will have access on the `flask_login.current_user`. This should happen because flask-login integration should make flask call this function before every request.

```
@app.login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(_id):
  try:
    user = users[_id]
    return user
  except KeyError:
    return None
```

However, the actual behavior is different. The called endpoint `/home` is not able to access `current_user` after redirection

```
@home_bp.route('/home')
def home():
    print(f"Current User: {current_user}") #This returns that the user is AnonymousMixin
    return render_template(....)
```

Yet if the page is refreshed (the endpoint is called directly), it is able to pick the `current_user` and it prints the information of the logged in user.

In other words, on redirection, the `login_manager.user_loader` flask-login callback is not called, but it is called as usual when the endpoint is called directly.

I am not sure if I missed or misunderstand something, or if there is a peculiar bug that causes this behavior.